# Can I bridge between a local mercurial repos and a remote bazaar repos?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, bazaar

I'm looking for the mercurial+bazaar equivalent of hg-git.  I intend to use this for occasional cooperation to avoid learning the quirks and tricks surrounding YAVCS: I'd prefer to do use one client for as many operations as possible and thus avoid the time investment for a tool not directly useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you do get bzr-hg (https://launchpad.net/bzr-hg) but its not complete yet.
You also get bzr-svn and bzr-git, so I'm using bazaar as my one tool to access them all, but it does not always work perfectly yet.

Comment: It's only one-way access, though - there's a similar plugin for HG too, but I suppose I'll just stick with patches, then.

Comment: bzr-hg is nowhere near usable at the moment.